# How to make a checklist with exactly 1 or 2 possible boxes checked in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I need to make a checklist in HTML, but I need to have only 1 *or* 2 possible boxes checked. I can use JavaScript if necessary.

Here is my code:

```
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox">Option 1</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox">Option 2</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox">Option 3</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox">Option 4</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox">Option 6</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox">Option 7</li>
</ul>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript limit selected checkboxes to 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43456868/javascript-limit-selected-checkboxes-to-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen to changes and keep track of the number of checked inputs as follows:

```js
let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox');
let count = 0;
for(let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++){
     checkboxes[i].addEventListener('change', function(){
          if(!event.target.checked)
               count--;
          else{
               if(count == 2)
                    event.target.checked = false;
               else
                    count++;
          }
     });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox">Option 1</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox">Option 2</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox">Option 3</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox">Option 4</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox">Option 6</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox">Option 7</li>
</ul>
```